# Tkinter: Trying to Create a Grid of Buttons then add each one to a Dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create an 8x8 grid of buttons in Tkinter within a toplevel window. I also want to add each one of these buttons to a dictionary if possible. When I try to do this, however, the window (which was openein before I tried to add the buttons) never opens and the Python Launcher stops responding. (Sorry for anything that is poorly done/inefficient, this is the first thing I've tried coding on my own)

```
def new_game(x,y, difficulty):
    global dimension
    dimension = "%sx%s" %(x,y)
    game=Toplevel(TS)
    game.title("MineSweeper")
    game.geometry(dimension)
    game.title(difficulty)
    game.configure(background="Gray")
    my_frame = Frame(game)
    my_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
    title= Label(game, text="Minesweeper",bg="Gray",fg="red", font=("Helvetica",18, "bold"))
    title.pack()

    x=0
    y=0
    #Creating Easy Game Buttons
    easy_buttons=dict({})
    if difficulty == "Easy":
        for num in range (64):
            easy_buttons[num]=[Button(game,text="temp").grid(row=x,column=y)]
            y+=1
            if y==8:
                y=0
                x+=1
```

Comment: Generally speaking, mixing `.grid` and `.pack` in the same widget can result in some pretty funky behavior (IIRC, that includes hanging the UI forever while tkinter tries to negotiate the placements of the sub-widgets).  Also note, your `easy_buttons` values will all be `[None]` since `Widget.grid` returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm):

> **Warning:** Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution that both managers are happy with. Instead of waiting, kill the application, and take another look at your code. A common mistake is to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.

I'd advise you change the layout slightly.  You can create a 2 row x 1 column grid.  The first row is your `title` and the second row would be a `Frame`.  Then you can put your 8x8 grid of buttons on the `Frame`.

---

You've also inadvertently stepped into another `tkinter` landmine -- the `.grid` method *always* returns `None`, so your dictionary will just hold a bunch of `[None]` values and none of the buttons.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I'll try fixing those things and see how it works then.